# useEffect is getting in a loop

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, authprovider

I am trying to implement in my app.js a simple Protect Route Middleware.
If the user is authenticated, he can not go to "/login" and "/". I also made a simple function in app.js, which is checking if the user is not authenticated. If he is not authenticated, he will be redirected from "/home" to "/login". Unfortunately my website does not stop to refresh if I am doing that.
For example : If am not authenticated and I trying to visit "/home", I will be redirect to "/login", but then go in refresh loop ! :(

app.js

```
function App() {
  const authenticated = useSelector((state) => state.user.authenticated)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
   if (!authenticated) {
    window.location.href = '/login'
  } 
  }, [
    // I tried every possible combination
  ])

  

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/home' component={HomePage} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />

         
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

ProtectedToute.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authenticated = useSelector((state) => state.user.authenticated)
  console.log('Route', authenticated)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (authenticated) {
          return <Redirect to='/home' />
         
        } else {
          return (
        
            <Component {...props} />
          )
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

Comment: have you tried to use history object?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined is the error if I do history.push('/')

Comment: you need to use useHistory hook which is from react-router, it returns the history ```const history = useHistory()```

Comment: import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'    const history = useHistory()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authenticated) {
      history.push('/')
    }
  }, []). same error :(

Comment: I If I do that in homepage.js it is working I am just confused

Comment: It’s really strange in App.js I am not able to use usehistory but in homepage.js it is working fine

Comment: Yes it's because you pass history with the Router tag.

Comment: So I have to put in Homepage.js ?